# Check how many columns contain value in each row of table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have these two tables in MSSQL database.

**Student Preferences Tables**
(This table has preferences columns numbered from 1-7 in database)

```
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Student Name |   Preference 1|  Preference 2 | Preference 3  |Group ID
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Student A    |   Student G   |   Student F   |  Student G    |
    Student B    |   Student H   |   Student K   |  Student L    |
    Student C    |   Student I   |   Student A
    Student D    |   Student H   |   Student K
    Student E
    Student F
    Student G
    Student H
    Student I
    Student J
    Student K
    Student L
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Groups Table**

```
 |Group ID |
     ---------
    1
    2
    3
    ----------
```

I am creating groups of student based on preferences(preferred partners/team mates) entered by student. 
Each group can have 5-8 students.Not all students will enter preferences.
To create a group i will check for the students who have entered 4-7 preferences and add them to a group.
For example, Student A has entered 4 preferences. Including student A now i have 5 students minimum number required for group. So, i would like to insert in "Groups table" and retrieve that number and insert in "Group ID" column for each student.
In cases if student has entered less than 4 preferences, i will have to create a new "group id" and assign to students but i also have to check that 5-8 students per group condition is not breached.

Can someone please guide me on this.
How to check for rows where more than 4 preference columns contain data(names)?
If students with more than 4 preferences exist, than how can i insert new record in Groups table(Group ID (auto-inc)) and retrieve it back to insert in Student Preference table. 
How can i check 5-8 students condition is not breaching before inserting group id?
I am trying to find out how can these problems be solved (using c# or SQL) in easiest way?
I am writing application in C#.

Comment: The first one is an actual table?

Comment: @SJuan76 it has preference columns from 1-7 in database here i have just written 3, i might make separate table for preferences if needed.

Comment: Before asking for queries you need to have a normalized data model; I see `preference` more as an `N:N` relationship of student on itself than anything (of course that will depend of your semantics).

Comment: @SJuan76 the reason i didn't normalize the database is i am trying to keep it as simple as possible. I can make changes to the database later if but right now i am trying to solve the above mentioned problems.

Comment: Wrong, you are not keeping it simple (if you were, you would not be asking questions here). Wrong, you have problems because you do not have a normalized database.

Comment: @SJuan76 should i create a new table_Preferences(StudentID(f_k), Pref1......pref7)?

Comment: Andrew's answer is pretty much what I would do (although I prefer more hints and directions and less code). You should mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty horrible table design.  You'd probably be a lot better off with multiple tables.  One for student/group, and one for student/preference.  So:

```
T_STUDENTS
StudentID
GroupID

T_STUDENT_PREFERENCES
StudentID
Preference
```

Then you could simply query your preferences table:

```
select
studentid,
count(preference)
from
pref_table
group by
studentid
having count(preference) >4
```

Since you can't do that, you'll have to do something gnarly with case statements.

Something like

```
select
student,
case when preference1 <>''  then 1 else 0 end as pref1 //or something to check for empty/null,
case when preference2 <>'' then 1 else 0 end as pref2
....
```

then add up the 7 columns and filter for your desired number of preferences.

Comment: I am normalizing the database now. So are you suggesting i create Pref_table with 2 columns(StudentID,Preference). Each student will have choice to store 7 other student names as his/her preferred team mates.

Comment: Yes, that exactly it.  The database can't control how many preferences any given student has.  You'd have to drive that from your front end application.

Comment: If each student adds 7 preferences, i will be inserting same StudentID 7 times in Pref_table?

Comment: yep.  Consider it a transaction, if that helps any.  Also, this really isn't "normalizing" data exactly, don't get hung up on that.